# View not found in container hierarchy crash while adding View constraints programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Although the crash message is very clear but I have checked my code and everything seems to be looking fine. My only worry is because I am setting constraints on a view which is being set as accessory view for keyboard, could that be a reason why entire view hierarchy is not set properly.

Here is what I am doing:

**Step 1:** Create a custom accessory view (a number bar from 0 to 9) and put it on top of regular keyboard.

```
MyAccessoryView *anAccessoryView = [[MyAccessoryView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 46.0f)];
anAccessoryView.delegate = self;
self.textField.inputAccessoryView = anAccessoryView;
```

**Step 2:** In custom accessory view (subview of UIView), add buttons and related handling. Add them to super view and then call a method after a delay of 1 second to add constraints.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)iFrame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:iFrame]) {
        [self refresh];
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    }

    [self setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    return self;
}


- (void)refresh {
    if (!self.layoutController) {
        self.layoutController = [[MyAccessoryViewLayoutController alloc] init];
    }

    self.backgroundColor = [self.layoutController colorForNumericInputAccessory:self];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    NSMutableArray *buttonsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

    // Adding number keys to the accessory view and setting thier properties
    for (NSInteger i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        MyAccessoryViewNumericButton *aKeyboardButton = [MyAccessoryViewNumericButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        aKeyboardButton.tag = i;
        aKeyboardButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32.0, 44);

        [aKeyboardButton setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)i % 10] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSString *aButtonImageTitle = [self.layoutController buttonNormalStateImageNameForIndex:(i % 10) forNumericInputAccessory:self];
        [aKeyboardButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:aButtonImageTitle] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        aKeyboardButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [aKeyboardButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [aKeyboardButton setExclusiveTouch:YES];
        aKeyboardButton.titleLabel.font = [self.layoutController fontForButtonTitlesForNumericInputAccessory:self];


        if (self.layoutController.interfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            aKeyboardButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        } else {
            NSString *aButtonHighlightedImageTitle = [self.layoutController buttonHighlightedStateImageNameForIndex:(i % 10) forNumericInputAccessory:self];
            [aKeyboardButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:aButtonHighlightedImageTitle] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        }

        aKeyboardButton.hidden = NO;
        aKeyboardButton.enabled = YES;
        aKeyboardButton.tag = i;
        [aKeyboardButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self addSubview:aKeyboardButton];
        [buttonsArray addObject:aKeyboardButton];

        if (self.layoutController.interfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            UIImage *aPressedButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.layoutController buttonHighlightedStateImageNameForIndex:(i % 10) forNumericInputAccessory:self]];
            CGRect aPressedButtonViewFrame = [self.layoutController frameForPressedButtonViewWithIndex:(i % 10) forNumericInputAccessory:self];
            UIView *aPressedButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:aPressedButtonViewFrame];
            aPressedButtonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            aPressedButtonView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            aPressedButtonView.hidden = YES;

            UIImageView *aPressedButtonImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:aPressedButtonImage];
            aPressedButtonImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, aPressedButtonViewFrame.size.width, aPressedButtonViewFrame.size.height);
            aPressedButtonImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;
            aPressedButtonImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            CGRect aPressedButtonLabelFrame = [self.layoutController frameForPressedButtonLabelWithIndex:(i % 10) forNumericInputAccessory:self];
            UILabel *aPressedButtonLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:aPressedButtonLabelFrame];
            aPressedButtonLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            aPressedButtonLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)i % 10];
            aPressedButtonLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            aPressedButtonView.tag = i + 100;

            aPressedButtonLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica-Bold" size: 44.0f];
            aPressedButtonLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.95f green: 0.95f blue: 0.95f alpha: 1.0f];
            aPressedButtonLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.75f);

            if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation])) {
                aPressedButtonImageView.frame = CGRectMake(aPressedButtonImageView.frame.origin.x, aPressedButtonImageView.frame.origin.y - 2.0f, aPressedButtonImageView.frame.size.width, aPressedButtonImageView.frame.size.height);
            }

            [aPressedButtonView addSubview:aPressedButtonImageView];

            [aPressedButtonView addSubview:aPressedButtonLabel];

            [self addSubview:aPressedButtonView];

        }
    }

    CALayer *aLightGreyBorder = [CALayer layer];
    aLightGreyBorder.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y + 1.0f, self.bounds.size.width, 1.0f);
    UIColor *aColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:178.0f/255.0f green:184.0f/255.0f blue:191.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    aLightGreyBorder.backgroundColor = [aColor CGColor];
    [self.layer insertSublayer:aLightGreyBorder atIndex:0];

    CALayer *aDarkGreyBorder = [CALayer layer];
    aDarkGreyBorder.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width, 1.0f);
    UIColor *aSecondColor;

    aSecondColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:100.0f/255.0f green:100.0f/255.0f blue:100.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    aDarkGreyBorder.backgroundColor = [aSecondColor CGColor];
    [self.layer insertSublayer:aDarkGreyBorder atIndex:0];

    if (self.layoutController.interfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        for (UIView *aPressedButtonView in [self subviews]) {
            if ([aPressedButtonView isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
                [self bringSubviewToFront:aPressedButtonView];
            }
        }
    }

    // Now lets add constaints
    [self performSelector:@selector(addConstraintsForButtons:) withObject:buttonsArray afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

**Step 3:** Add constraints to all buttons (0 to 9). Here, I am showing only first 2 buttons.

```
- (void)addConstraintsForButtons:(NSMutableArray *)iButtons {
    // First Button
    MyAccessoryViewNumericButton *firstButton = (MyAccessoryViewNumericButton *)iButtons[0];

    // Left edge constraint for First button
    NSLayoutConstraint *leading =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:firstButton
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                  multiplier:1.0f
                                  constant:4.f];

    [self addConstraint:leading];

    // Middle in the super view
    NSLayoutConstraint *vertical =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:firstButton
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                   multiplier:1.0f
                                   constant:0];

    [self addConstraint:vertical];

    // Width-Height Constraint for First button
    [self addWHContraintForButton:firstButton];


    // Second Button
    MyAccessoryViewNumericButton *secondButton = (MyAccessoryViewNumericButton *)iButtons[1];

    // Left edge constraint for First button
    NSLayoutConstraint *secondLeading =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                        constraintWithItem:secondButton
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:firstButton
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                        multiplier:1.0f
                                        constant:4.f];

    [secondButton addConstraint:secondLeading];

    // Middle in the super view
    NSLayoutConstraint *secondVertical =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                         constraintWithItem:secondButton
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                         toItem:firstButton
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                         multiplier:1.0f
                                         constant:0];

    [secondButton addConstraint:secondVertical];


    // Width-Height Constraint for Second button
    [self addWHContraintForButton:secondButton];

    // Add constaints to rest of the buttons...
}

- (void)addWHContraintForButton:(MyAccessoryViewNumericButton *)iButton {
    CGFloat buttonWidth = 32.0f;
    CGFloat buttonHeight = 44.0f;

    // Height Constraint
    NSLayoutConstraint *height = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:iButton
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:nil
                                  attribute:0
                                  multiplier:0
                                  constant:buttonHeight];

    // Width Constraint
    NSLayoutConstraint *width = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                 constraintWithItem:iButton
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:nil
                                 attribute:0
                                 multiplier:0
                                 constant:buttonWidth];

    [iButton addConstraint:height];
    [iButton addConstraint:width];
}
```

But when I run this code, it crashes with following message:

```
View not found in container hierarchy: <MyAccessoryViewNumericButton: 0x7fb506036f90; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (0 0; 32 44); opaque = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb506039c70>>
    That view's superview: <MyAccessoryView: 0x7fb503ddfb50; frame = (0 0; 320 46); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb503dc1fe0>>
```

This is what I see when debug this (tried by setting constraints in `keyboardDidShow:` and `didMoveToSuperview` methods):

```
(lldb) po [secondButton superview]
<MyAccessoryView: 0x7fcd6d04f6c0; frame = (0 0; 320 46); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcd6adf5ed0>>

(lldb) po [[secondButton superview] superview]
<UIInputSetHostView: 0x7fcd6d0346c0; frame = (0 522; 320 262); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcd6adef270>>

(lldb) po [[[secondButton superview] superview] superview]
<UIInputSetContainerView: 0x7fcd6d014000; frame = (0 0; 320 568); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcd6add78d0>>

(lldb) po [[[[secondButton superview] superview] superview] superview]
<UITextEffectsWindow: 0x7fcd6d033c30; frame = (0 0; 320 568); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7fcd6d034250>>

(lldb) po [[[[[secondButton superview] superview] superview] superview] superview]
0x0000000000000000
```

Although view has a parent. Can someone please advise here.

Comment: You answered your own question.  It's not in the hierarchy.  It's not enough to have a superview.  At some point, the superview('s superview) has to be a subview of a window currently displayed.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. How do we handle this situation for keyboard accessory view? I have also tried adding constraints on keyBoadWillAppear method as well but no gain.

Comment: Have your view override `didMoveToSuperview` and add the constraints there.

Comment: No, I am not. Let me try this out.

Comment: Unfortunately that also leading to same crash @Avi. Let me try in `keyboardDidAppear` instead.